# I can't install android app when react-native project is first created

Tags: android, react-native

There is an issue when I create project

```
yarn run v1.22.17
```

$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 10 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> 11 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 9 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @3ddaca54

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @3ddaca54

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

```
at makeError (/Users/junochoi/Documents/ReactNative/TodoApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /Users/junochoi/Documents/ReactNative/TodoApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/junochoi/Documents/ReactNative/TodoApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/junochoi/Documents/ReactNative/TodoApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

Here is my $ react-native info

```
System:
OS: macOS 12.2
CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
Memory: 97.39 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
```

Binaries:
Node: 16.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.17 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/yarn
npm: 8.3.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm
Watchman: 2022.02.14.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
Android SDK:
API Levels: 29, 30, 31, 32
Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0
System Images: android-29 | Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-32 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111
Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 17.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.67.2 => 0.67.2
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding the code below to gradient.properties.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M —add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED —add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED —add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED —add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED —add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```